# VS Code Stop Showing InlayHints Types on methods/functions/objects/etc

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have enabled viewing the types in VS Code, and now I don't remember how to turn it off or where I turned it on.

I've disabled all my extensions to make sure it wasn't one of them haha. So it looks like a VS Code Setting I can't seem to find.
[image: Tags showing the types of different methods,objects in VSCode]

As shown above here pointed out by the red box and arrows.

Greatly appreciate it, driving me crazy at the moment however very helpful at first.

Comment: Assuming this is Typescript: there's only one type shown in the screen shot (`:string`). The other 3 are parameter names. If you don't want to use explicit types, switch to Javascript (rename the file to *.js).

Comment: Thanks Mike - yeah screenshot is limited there, and true not just types. This is not typescript, and is a .jsx - hoping to remove all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it, hope this helps someone else - it was the inlayHints for javascript displaying all that.

Open up settings for VS Code, Ctrl + Shit + P to open command palette, type "Open Settings" and selected the JSON option. I had the following set to true, switched to false.

```
  "javascript.inlayHints.enumMemberValues.enabled": false,
  "javascript.inlayHints.functionLikeReturnTypes.enabled": false,
  "javascript.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled": "all",
  "javascript.inlayHints.propertyDeclarationTypes.enabled": false,
  "javascript.inlayHints.parameterTypes.enabled": false,
  "javascript.inlayHints.variableTypes.enabled": false,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find it under `Inlay Hints` via the UI too rather than editing json:

[image]